# Change background of htmltablerowelement in jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building an application in MVC3 C# 4.0

In my view, i have a table.  Each row has a class `myrowclass`
I can get the rows of the table in jquery by just doing `$(".myrowclass")`
It returns a collection of `htmltablerowelement`

Now I want to change the background of the row 1 but I am unable to do so

The HTML table has many .
Each  has many 
Each  has one  tag.

i am clicking a row and on click event of the  inside each , i want to trigger an event that will change the background color of this.parentElement.parentElement

this.parentElement.parentElement.css("background-color", "green"); <-- not working

But I keep getting the error that HtmlTableRowElement does not have .css property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change CSS styles use:

```
$(".myrowclass").css("background-color", "green");
```

To add CSS classes to the element(s) use:

```
$(".myrowclass").addClass("greencssclass");
```

Comment: i tried but doesn't work. also i want to have all rows have the class myrowclass too because i get all rows with myrowclass and do some calculation on them

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about jQuery's [**`.css()`**](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

```
$(".myrowclass").css("background-color","green");
```

Or [**`.addClass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
$(".myrowclass").addClass("greencssclass");
```

Comment: doesn;t work. here, changing css does not change the colour AT ALL

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker if its not working there is more than being stated about your code and your app. Give us an example of what your actual table looks like from an HTML level, cause changing the background-color or adding a class like Derek says should have it working.

Comment: I get object#<HtmlTableRowElement> has no method 'css'

Comment: from your jsfiddler example, Imagine, I want to do this:  $(".myrowclass")[0].css("background-color", "green");  And it won't work...

Comment: i've changed the question a bit. i have cut many of the parts but basically, i am clicking a row and on click event of the <input> inside each <td>, i want to trigger an event that will change the background color of this.parentElement.parentElement

Comment: Managed to get it by row[0].style.backgroundColor = "red"

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker - Of course `$(".myrowclass")[0].css()` will not work, because when you put `[0]` at the end, it is not a jQuery object anymore.